# Display single product attribute value on Shop page (Woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I am trying to display a single attribute ('size') value on shop page. I used the following code to show all values, tried to adapt to to show a single attribute, but with no success...

Can you please help me adapt the code to only display values of the attribute 'size'?

```
// Get the attributes
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
// Start the loop
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) : 
    // Check and output, adopted from /templates/single-product/product-attributes.php
    if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {
        $values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );
    } else {
        // Convert pipes to commas and display values
        $values = array_map( 'trim', explode( WC_DELIMITER, $attribute['value'] ) );
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );
    }
endforeach;
```

Can you please let me know how to modify it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `global $product` then use `get_attribute()` method of that product object, like below-

```
$size = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_size' );
```

And you can also get that by below code-

```
global $product;
$size = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_size', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
```

Rememeber you need to use must the `global $product`.

Comment: Thanks, and how do I then display the values (separated by space)?

Comment: I've not understood what are you pointing at by "separated by spaces"!!  And if you think this answer helped you please accept it.

Comment: It did help, thank you. I am simply having trouble displaying the values in my template correctly. Can you advise how to display them?

Comment: Can you provide any visible link or picture how you wanna show them? @user3767576

Comment: http://nadinka.webd.pl/modafirma/category/clothing/ - on product image hover you will see an Available sizes box, I want to display all size values assigned to the product there. I tried to display them using $echo, but only the first value appears (there is more than one for each product)

Comment: Got it. I'm kinda busy right now. Give me some time. I'll get back to you. ok may friend?

Comment: The code that worked for me is `     $size = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_size' );
global $product;
$size = array_values( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_size', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
$prodsizes=implode(", ",$size);
echo $prodsizes;`

Comment: To show a specific attribute called "Item Dimensions":

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_product_formated_dimensions_table', 25 );

function display_product_formated_dimensions_table(){
    global $product;

 $item_dimensions = $product->get_attribute( 'Item Dimensions' );
    if ( $product->has_attributes() ) {
        echo '<table class="shop_attributes"><tr>
            <th>' . __( 'Item Dimensions', 'woocommerce' ) . '</th>
            <td class="product_dimensions">' . esc_html( $item_dimensions ) . '</td>
        </tr></table>';
    }
}

Answer (score -1):

```
$product = wc_get_product();
echo $product->get_attribute( 'Size' );
```

Comment: Could you explain why is this an answer?